# python regular expression for dynamic range

Tags: python, regex

This is the first time I am using `Regular Expression` so any help will be grateful. I am scraping from `Font Awesome`

```
['fa', 'fa-american-sign-language-interpreting']///what I want: fa-american-sign-language-interpreting
['fa', 'fa-viadeo-square']///what I want: fa-viadeo-square
['fa', 'fa-adjust']///what I want: fa-adjust
```

This is what I do:

```
(fa-)[a-z]+(-)?[a-z]+(-)?[a-z]+(-)?[a-z]+
```

Which I think it works for now, but if there is more than 4 `-`, then this line won't work. I believe it should be shorter and more dynamic. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KISS, Make the second part to repeat one or more times.

```
\bfa(?:-[a-z]+)+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eS8jW3/2)

Comment: All have good answer. I just choose the KISS. By the way, what is `?` for? I understand it is `0 or 1` but how do it work in this case?

Comment: `(?:)` called non-capturing group which works same as capturing group `()` but it won't capture any single chars..

Answer (score 0):

`/(fa-(?:-?\w+)+)/g`

Demo is at http://regexr.com/3d97e

Answer (score 0):

Considering the format it has, the first entry will only be `fa` but second will start with `fa-` and you need the second one:

```
(fa-[\w-]+)
```

[Regex Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/gW1sS9/4)

Here a working demo on [Ideone](https://ideone.com/kY3hEg).

```
import re

s = """
     ['fa', 'fa-american-sign-language-interpreting']
     ['fa', 'fa-viadeo-square']
     ['fa', 'fa-adjust']
    """

m = re.findall(r"fa-[\w-]+", s)
print(m)

# ['fa-american-sign-language-interpreting', 'fa-viadeo-square', 'fa-adjust']
```